# azure download key/secret not working- RequiredArgumentMissingError

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I am trying to download ssh key for a VM stored in Azure keyvault. But getting below error:

I tried to download it as secret and key both, but command fails with same error. What am I missing? (I am new to this, doing this for first time)

```
az keyvault key download  –-vault-name keyvaultname —name Test-SSHKey —e utf-8 —f  ~/.ssh/test-agent.pem

    RequiredArgumentMissingError: the following arguments are required: --file/-f
    Try this: 'az keyvault key download --vault-name <MyKeyVault> -n <MyKey> -e <PEM> -f <mykey.pem>'
    Still stuck? Run 'az keyvault key download --help' to view all commands or go to 'https://aka.ms/cli_ref' to learn more

    ➜  ~ az keyvault key download  –-vault-name keyvaultname —name Test-SSHKey —f " ~/.ssh/test-agent.pem"
    
    RequiredArgumentMissingError: the following arguments are required: --file/-f
    Try this: 'az keyvault key download --vault-name <MyKeyVault> -n <MyKey> -e <PEM> -f <mykey.pem>'
    Still stuck? Run 'az keyvault key download --help' to view all commands or go to 'https://aka.ms/cli_ref' to learn more
```

➜  ~ az keyvault key download  –-vault-name keyvaultname —name Test-SSHKey —file  "~/.ssh/test-agent.pem"

```
    RequiredArgumentMissingError: the following arguments are required: --file/-f
    Try this: 'az keyvault key download --vault-name <MyKeyVault> -n <MyKey> -e <PEM> -f <mykey.pem>'
    Still stuck? Run 'az keyvault key download --help' to view all commands or go to 'https://aka.ms/cli_ref' to learn more

    ➜  ~ az keyvault key download  –-vault-name keyvaultname —-name Test-SSHKey -—file  "~/.ssh/test-agent.pem"
    
    RequiredArgumentMissingError: the following arguments are required: --file/-f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow your characters got messed up it seems: You don't have two dashes `--`. Instead you have for some reason this, a little bit longer dash-like char `—`. Make sure you only use proper dashes

Comment: haha..still I see them as normal as in my new command in terminal(copied from another post) and it worked. This time gave encoding as PEM though.
az keyvault key download --name Test-SSHKey --vault-name xxx --encoding PEM --file ~/.ssh/test.pem

Thanks a lot!